# How can I track click counts for multiple elements with a jQuery selector that matches all of the elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

I have a set of buttons with the same `clickme` class:

```
<button class="clickme">Click Me 1</button>
<button class="clickme">Click Me 2</button>
<button class="clickme">Click Me 3</button>
```

I also have a click handler for the `clickme` class:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function () {
  // do stuff
});
```

How can I keep track of click counts *for each individual button* in this scenario?

Note: I've provided my own answer below, but I'm not sure if mine is the *best* solution.  I think I could improve the brevity.

Comment: Why did you ask a question and then answer it yourself with a working fiddle _literally_ the same minute?  If you're looking for a _better_ solution then you should include your solution in the question and ask specifically if there is a better way.

Comment: @MikeEdwards: Your points are valid and I will do what you suggested in the future.  I certainly don't want to give the impression that I am "gaming" the system when all I really want to do is share my ideas.  I could care less about my reputation points.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz

Comment: thanks for the links. read and noted. Personally I like the edit you made, it makes it easier as an answerer to invest the time even though there is already a working solution provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be very simple exaple and good example for you:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function () {
          var count = parseInt($(this).data('click'), 10) || 0;
          count++;
          $(this).data('click',count);
          alert(count);    
        });
```

HERE : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashapkota/5AssN/)

Comment: For god's sake, please always explicitely set the second (radix) argument when using `parseInt`. That is, unless you like accidential octal interpretations ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Just wanted to add that I think we could replace `count=count+1;` with a simple `count++;` for even more brevity awesomeness. :-)

Comment: @vzwick: `var count = parseInt($(this).data('click'), 10) || 0;`, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem by storing the click count on the individual elements like this:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function () {
    var that = $(this);

    if (typeof (that.data( 'clickCount')) === 'undefined') {
        that.data( 'clickCount', 1);
    } else {
        var clickCount = that.data( 'clickCount');
        clickCount++;
        that.data( 'clickCount', clickCount);
    }

    alert(that.text() + ' clicked ' + that.data( 'clickCount') + ' times.');

    });
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9jc/1/).

Is this the *best* approach?

Comment: Why did you bother storing `$(this)` when the context of `this` doesn't change?

Comment: I just copied it from my fiddle that does some additional work that _does_ change the context of `this`: `$('#results').append('<p>' + that.text() + ' clicked ' + that.data( 'clickCount') + ' times.</p>');`

Comment: No, I take that back: the additional work doesn't seem to change the context after all (http://jsfiddle.net/6q9jc/2/).  I guess the only reason I can give now is `that` is shorter to type than `$(this)`.

Comment: @BrianGraham Also, pre-caching $(this) is beneficial performance-wise - jQuery won't have to perform the (relatively expensive) DOM lookup over and over again.